# angular ui tooltip triggers ng-disabled of other buttons when hover on button

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap

I using ui bootstrap tooltip plugin with something like this:

```
<button type="button" uib-tooltip="new item">
    new item
</button>
<button ng-disabled="vm.testDisabled()">
    search
</button>

angular.module('rgh').controller('CourseController', CourseController);

function CourseController () {
    function testDisabled() {
        console.log('testDisabled called')
        return false;
    }
}
```

but the problem is that when i hover on **new item** button, i see the `testDisabled called` logs in chrome console, i think its inappropriate behavior from `uib-tooltip`.

how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: look: each time you interact with the page angular runs so named $digest cycle(you can search this name). it means it evaluate every single expression you integrated(actually it runs watchers created from expressions - but it's on lower level). for hover it is literally such a case(otherwise page would be frozen completely) but once you move mouse over the button -> some code is running -> angular runs $digest check just in case, because something might be changed in different place

Answer (score 0):

It's not inappropriate, it's how angular works! when you pass over your button and the tooltip shows the digest loop runs, because you've provided your `ngDisabled` with a function, that function will run on each digest cycle (even when it is not needed) because it's returned result will be used to tell angular if it should disable the input or not!!

To avoid this, pass `ngDisabled` with a variable that will be changed in your controller on certain conditions

```
<button ng-disabled="vm.isTestDisabled">
    search
</button>
```